# Camunda 8 Identity not connecting to existing Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, identity, camunda

I am trying to connect Camunda 8 Identity to our ecisting keycloak (v23.0.7) using Camunda Helm chart. I have the following definition for Keycloak connection

```
global:
  identity:
    keycloak:
      url:
        protocol: "https"
        host: "keycloak.keycloak.svc.cluster.local"
        port: "443"
      contextPath: "/"
      realm: "/realms/camunda-platform"
      auth:
        adminUser: "admin"
        existingSecret: "keycloak-auth"
        existingSecretKey: "admin-password"

identity:
  keycloak:
    enabled: false
```

The pod or Identity container fails with following error:

```
ingframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frontendController': Invocation of init method failed
2024-03-23 08:58:26.371 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'frontendController': Invocation of init method failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:222) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1760) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:596) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949) ~[spring-context-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615) ~[spring-context-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.9.jar!/:3.1.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) [spring-boot-3.1.9.jar!/:3.1.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) [spring-boot-3.1.9.jar!/:3.1.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) [spring-boot-3.1.9.jar!/:3.1.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) [spring-boot-3.1.9.jar!/:3.1.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-3.1.9.jar!/:3.1.9]
        at io.camunda.identity.Application.main(Application.java:21) [classes!/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [identity.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) [identity.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [identity.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) [identity.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected authority at index 7: http://
        at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at io.camunda.identity.config.IdentityCommon.basePath(IdentityCommon.java:62) ~[classes!/:?]
        at io.camunda.identity.frontend.controller.FrontendController.initialize(FrontendController.java:53) ~[classes!/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:401) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 7: http://
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at io.camunda.identity.config.IdentityCommon.basePath(IdentityCommon.java:62) ~[classes!/:?]
        at io.camunda.identity.frontend.controller.FrontendController.initialize(FrontendController.java:53) ~[classes!/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMethod.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:401) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-beans-6.0.17.jar!/:6.0.17]
        ... 26 more
```

- I have double checked the password in the secret and I am able to login to Keycloak admin panel using same credentials.
- The chart uses Camunda v8.4.5. I have tried Identity v8.5.0-alpha2 but I get same error
- According to [Component Requirements](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/reference/supported-environments/#component-requirements) only Keycloak 21.x and 22.x are supported. I have tried the same setup with Keycloak 22.x but it failed with same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by introducing fullURL:KC_URL in values file

```
identity:
  fullURL: "https://keycloak.keycloak.svc.cluster.local:8443"
```

The complete fix and discussion can be find in Camunda community post: https://forum.camunda.io/t/identity-not-connecting-to-existing-keycloak/51379